# LibreOffice does not detect Windows fonts

Tags: windows, libreoffice, fonts

I have installed tts-mscorefonts-installer. That lets me use Windows fonts. I can find and use them in Gnumeric and they appear in Fonts. But they do not appear in any of the libreOffice Suite of applications. Furthermore, when a document contains one of those fonts is opened in LibreOffice the Font is italicized, and does not appear correctly.

Comment: Would you please specify which Ubuntu and Libreoffice versions are/were you using? If you are a terminal-user, launch `lsb_release -a` `libreoffice --version`

Answer (score 3):

Recent versions of LibreOffice (5.3 and above) have stopped using  PS Type 1 URW fonts. This seems to be a policy decision as discussed in [PS Type 1 URW fonts missing in LibreOffice 5.3.0.0.beta1 and 5.3.0.0.beta2](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104701).

> All code supporting Type 1 fonts have been removed in the upcoming 5.4 release and I don’t see anyone volunteering to bring it back and adding the code required for the new layout engine to support them.
>
> A better investment, going forward is to find a non-Type 1 replacement of these fonts, to convert them to OpenType using AFDKO or FontForge.

Even if these fonts are installed on your system and other applications such as Gnumeric use them, LibreOffice won't.

Sources for similar fonts are provided in the link above.

You could also go through [Shortage of Fonts in LibreOffice 5.3.0.3](https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg50793.html) and the responses, [one of which states](https://listarchives.libreoffice.org/global/users/msg50828.html) that

> The decision was made by the Engineering Steering Committee, in order to
>   allow for implementation of the new rendering framework code.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I cannot see and select the font (Times New Roman) from the fonts list, I have managed to make it work by typing the exact name of the font in the selection box.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1176549)