# Fonts disappear from list in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

I have a number of true-type fonts installed in LibreOffice (ubuntu 16.04). Until a recent update these appeared in the drop down list of fonts but now do not so, but will open when a document on that font is opened as they are listed in font manager.

Thank you

Comment: Possibly related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000231/libreoffice-does-not-detect-windows-fonts

Comment: Run command `fc-cache -fv` and check again if it helps.