# Install Microsoft ttf fonts on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, fonts

I'm new to use Ubuntu and need to use Microsoft TTF fonts with LibreOffice. Can anyone guide me how to do this using command line? I have already downloaded desired TTF file on my Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Some installed fonts won't be seen by LibreOffice. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1000246/248158

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just double click on the file and click install on the above corner, **.ttf** can be easily installed like this or change the format to **.otf**

Answer (score 5):

This should help.

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. Downloaded file name is Iskolapotha.ttf. This is For Sinhala language. I hope this should work.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [this more complete solution](https://needforbits.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/install-microsoft-windows-fonts-on-ubuntu-the-ultimate-guide/).

1. Windows Core fonts

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
   ```
2. Microsoft’s ClearType fonts (Windows Vista Fonts)

   ```
   wget https://gist.github.com/maxwelleite/10774746/raw/ttf-vista-fonts-installer.sh -q -O - | sudo bash
   ```
3. Microsoft Tahoma

   ```
   wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxwelleite/913b6775e4e408daa904566eb375b090/raw/cbfd8eb70184fa509fcab37dad7905676c93d587/ttf-ms-tahoma-installer.sh -q -O - | sudo bash
   ```
4. Wine Tahoma
5. Segoe UI

   ```
   $ sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
   $ cd /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeui.ttf?raw=true -O segoeui.ttf # regular
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeuib.ttf?raw=true -O segoeuib.ttf # bold
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeuib.ttf?raw=true -O segoeuii.ttf # italic
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeuiz.ttf?raw=true -O segoeuiz.ttf # bold italic
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeuil.ttf?raw=true -O segoeuil.ttf # light
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/seguili.ttf?raw=true -O seguili.ttf # light italic
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/segoeuisl.ttf?raw=true -O segoeuisl.ttf # semilight
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/seguisli.ttf?raw=true -O seguisli.ttf # semilight italic
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/seguisb.ttf?raw=true -O seguisb.ttf # semibold
   $ sudo wget -q https://github.com/martinring/clide/blob/master/doc/fonts/seguisbi.ttf?raw=true -O seguisbi.ttf # semibold italic
   $ fc-cache -f /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/
   ```
6. WPS Office Fonts (Symbol fonts)

   ```
   $ cd \tmp
   $ wget -O ttf-wps-fonts-master.zip https://github.com/IamDH4/ttf-wps-fonts/archive/master.zip
   $ unzip -LL ttf-wps-fonts-master.zip
   $ cd ttf-wps-fonts-master
   $ sudo ./install.sh
   ```

Answer (score 3):

(1) First, connect your computer to the internet, then open Terminal, Ctrl+Alt+T , then type

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

then press Enter.
[image]

(2) After a few seconds, this window comes out, press Tab and press enter on OK
[image]

(3) Then package installer comes out, press Tab and select Yes and press enter
[image]

(4) This will automatically take you back to the terminal, the process is running and end up automatically. 
[image]

(5) Now you are done. Enjoy typing MS Font in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
[image]